# Как закрыть автоматически Webview при выдаче ошибки страницы

Tags: java, android, webview

Подскажите пожалуйста как закрыть автоматически webview у пользователя если вылазит ошибка страницы

```js
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_browser);

        WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
       webView.loadUrl("http://keygarbx.beget.tech");

        WebViewClient webViewClient = new WebViewClient(){
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            public boolean ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return  true;
            }

            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            public boolean ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request){
                view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
                return true;
            }

            

        };


        
        webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);

        Button webback = (Button)findViewById(R.id.webback);
        webback.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try{
                    Intent intent = new Intent(BrowserActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);finish();
                }catch (Exception e) {
                } // конец конструкции
            }
        });






    }
  @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
    try{
        Intent intent = new Intent(BrowserActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);finish();
    }catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 4):

В клиенте `WebViewClient` если слушатель ошибок:

```
@Override
public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error){
finish();
}
```

или такой метод:

```
@Override
public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)
{
   super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
}
```

чтобы посмотреть данные методы, нужно перейти в тело:

```
WebViewClient webViewClient = new WebViewClient(){

};
```

нажать сочетание `ctrl+o` и вам высветится окошко с доступными методами. Можно ввести начало слова `error` и вам подсветит данные методы. Так как я не знаю что значит закрыть webview то я предположил что речь идет о закрытии активности.